# Java - Populating a Jtable with data from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So i have a JTable on a class.

```
table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "Location", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Nitrogen", "Phosphorus", "Potassium", "pH"
        }
    ));
    table.setBounds(35, 120, 507, 349);
    contentPane.add(table);
}
```

I want to populate the table using a data from another class. 
I have a class for displaying processed data(app is about processing Images using tensorflow) with the variables lat,lng,d1,d2,d3,d4 with each variable containing data.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke *setModel()* on your JTable instance.

You simply have to pass a model from a different source for example. Like:

```
setModel(simeOtherObject.generateTableModel());
```

In other words: another class can generate a model object. Or it provides some "neutral" data, such as a list, and then some helper code turns that into a Model object.

Where, honestly: having multiple classes work together in such ways is basic Java knowledge. If that is already overburdening you, then you should probably step back for a moment and learn more basics, before trying to create complex GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can add/remove data in a `JTable`. Below program demonstrates the use of `addRow()` and `setModel()`.

Note that `addRow()` method is there only in `DefaultTableModel`. So when you use some other table model, you have to use different methods.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PopulateTable
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "Location", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Nitrogen", "Phosphorus", "Potassium", "pH"
        }
    ));

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Add First Row");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(Data.getFirstRow());
      }
    });

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Set All Rows");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            Data.getAllRows(),
            new String[] {
                "Location", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Nitrogen", "Phosphorus", "Potassium", "pH"
            }
        ));
      }
    });

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    buttonPanel.add(button2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class Data
{
  private static Object[][] rows = new Object[][] {
      {"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1"},
      {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2"},
      {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3"},
      {"a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4"}
  };

  static Object[][] getAllRows()
  {
    return rows;
  }

  static Object[] getFirstRow()
  {
    return rows[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add more data inside the row object? Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: @Ryan, you mean changing a single cell value? Yes, it is possible. If you want to do that, the best approach would be to write a customer table model.

Comment: no. I meant adding more data inside the Row object. Let's say adding a5,b5,c5,......g5, i want to add more. Is it possible?

Comment: So let's say i want to store the user input inside the object, that's possible, right?

Comment: @Ryan, yes, it is possible.